# How can I get PayPal sandbox payments accepted automatically?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I integrate PayPal in my Symfony 4 App, but in sandbox payments still need to validated as we see in the picture behind.

[image]

How can I get payments accepted automatically ?

and I'm asking also if in Live mode, I'm going to have the same problem because I didn't have a business account to test it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is asking how to use paypal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the reason of that happens when the currency of the payment is not the same with the Paypal JS loaded script in client size.

So What you don't know that in the script loaded, the default Currency is **USD**, So you have to specify the currency in this script :

```
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?currency=EUR&client-id={{ data['clientId'] }}">
```

So in this case if the client pays with **EUR**, the payment is auto-accepted, else, you have to configure the strategy in Settings when you have two different currencies, So you have to login with your Business Account, then go to the Account Settings > Payment preferences > Block Payments.

Answer (score 0):

Is the issue that the payments are "PENDING"? Is the PayPal sandbox email not confirmed?

Log in with Sandbox account at https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/businessprofile/settings/email to check and resend any confirmation email

Then log in with Live developer account at https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Fnotifications%2F to read the message notifications and confirm the email

Comment: I'am using two test accounts provided by default in sandbox one is a business account and the other is personal, so I think the accounts didn't need to be confirmed :( did you have any other idea ?

Comment: If the email is confirmed, then other possibilities are that these are the first USD payments to an account that has a different primary balance (for example EUR) and you need to accept at least one USD payment to open a USD balance.